# Increase var_display_max_depth for xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

I recently installed xdebug on my ststem and wanted to increase xdebug.var_display_max_depth from 3 to 10. How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are two ways to do that. You can edit this value locally and globally too.

1. **Local setting**  ("*Local value*") in your own PHP file:

   ```php
   <?php  
       ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', '10');    
       // here comes your code...  
   ?>
   ```
2. **Global setting** ("*Master value*") in `php.ini`:

   1. First locate your `php.ini` file.


      - In `phpinfo()`, you can get to know where it is from *"Loaded Configuration File"* directive.
      - You can also locate it using command prompt/terminal:

        - Windows: `php --ini | findstr /C:"Loaded Configuration File"`
        - Linux/UNIX-like: `php --ini | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'`
      - using [`php_ini_loaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php): `<?php echo php_ini_loaded_file(); ?>`
3. **Open your `php.ini`** in a text editor file.
4. You have to put something like the following to this file (in this example, I'm using `php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll` <sub>(use http://xdebug.org/wizard.php to get to know which version you need)</sub>), and of course, you need to substitute `<path to your XDebug>` to the appropriate path:

   ```
   [Xdebug]  
   ;; <path to your XDebug> is like
   ;; C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext in Windows
   ;; (should be e.g. in PHP directory's "ext" subdir)
   ;; [backslash UNDER WINDOWS, / under UNIX-like operating systems]  
   zend_extension = "<path to your XDebug>\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts.dll"  

   ;; HERE comes the answer to your question, we set the mentioned variable to 10  
   xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 10
   ```

---

Simple as that... you can check the results in phpinfo's xdebug part in a table: there will be a "*Local value*" and a "*Master value*" column.

Here's a sample screenshot from my localhost server; in this example, the *global* configuration is `3`, but I set the *local value* to `10`, with the above mentioned `ini_set()`:

[image: Xdebug - var_display_max_depth (Local value/Master value)]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Sk8erPeter answer you can of course set it in your .htaccess file for faster management:

```
php_value xdebug.var_display_max_depth 10
```