# Making PHP var_dump() values display one line per value

Tags: php, line, var-dump

When I echo var_dump($_variable), I get one long, wrapping line with all varable's and values like

```
["kt_login_user"]=>  string(8) "teacher1" ["kt_login_id"]=>  string(3) "973" ["kt_campusID"]=>  string(4) "9088" ["kt_positionID"]=>  string(1) "5"
```

Is there a way I can make each value display on its own line for ease of reading? Something like this:

```
["kt_login_user"]=>  string(8) "teacher1" 
["kt_login_id"]=>  string(3) "973" 
["kt_campusID"]=>  string(4) "9088" 
["kt_positionID"]=>  string(1) "5"
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a `<pre>` tag around your `var_dump()`?

Answer (score 151):

Yes, try wrapping it with `<pre>`, e.g.:

```
echo '<pre>' , var_dump($variable) , '</pre>';
```

Comment: I tend to prefer print_r() though for arrays

Comment: Thanks, but I think maybe there is another way to do that, instead of using <pre> tag every time

Comment: If there is another way? sure, you can use nl2br if you want, but why would that be better?

Answer (score 44):

I usually have  a nice function to handle output of an array, just to pretty it up a bit when debugging.

```
function pr($data)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data); // or var_dump($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Then just call it

```
pr($array);
```

---

Or if you have an editor like that saves snippets so you can access them quicker instead of creating a function for each project you build or each page that requires just a quick test.

For `print_r`:

```
echo "<pre>", print_r($data, 1), "</pre>";
```

For `var_dump()`:

```
echo "<pre>", var_dump($data), "</pre>";
```

I use the above with PHP Storm. I have set it as a `pr` tab command.

Comment: Hint: code in `pr()` can be further simplified to this: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';`

Answer (score 16):

I've also researched this issue and not found the right answer.  This doesn't work for me:

```
echo '<pre>' . var_dump($variable) . '</pre>';
```

This will not provide a nice display of the array for me, with line breaks (I'm using Firefox 31.3.0)

However, after some experimentation, this solved the problem (notice the php is closed at first):

```
... ?> <pre><?php echo var_dump($variable) ?></pre> <?php ...
```

This solves the problem and displays a nice, easy-to-read array for me on my browser.  You see how the  tags are not wrapped in PHP; only the echo var_dump part is.

Comment: Tip: next time, [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). `var_dump` never returns the dumped value, this is why your second example worked... but still you don't need to do `echo var_dump..`... this will also works: `echo '<pre>';
var_dump($variable);
echo '</pre>';` or this: `<pre><?php var_dump($variable); ?></pre>`

Comment: It didn't work because you used periods instead of commas.

Answer (score 14):

If you got [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/display) installed, you can use it's `var_dump` replacement. Quoting:

> Xdebug replaces PHP's var_dump() function for displaying variables. Xdebug's version includes different colors for different types and places limits on the amount of array elements/object properties, maximum depth and string lengths. There are a few other functions dealing with variable display as well.

You will likely want to tweak a few of the following settings:

> There is a number of settings that control the output of Xdebug's modified var_dump() function: xdebug.var_display_max_children, xdebug.var_display_max_data and xdebug.var_display_max_depth. The effect of these three settings is best shown with an example. The script below is run four time, each time with different settings. You can use the tabs to see the difference.

But keep in mind that XDebug will significantly slow down your code, even when it's just loaded. It's not advisable to run in on production servers. But hey, you are not var_dumping on production servers anyway, are you?

Comment: it worked, In new update it was turned off. but it only shows a limited depth of array now.

Comment: @Towhid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998490/how-to-get-xdebug-var-dump-to-show-full-object-array :)

Answer (score 11):

[var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) will give you a nice output. Examples from the docs:

```
$a = array (1, 2, array ("a", "b", "c"));
echo '<pre>' . var_export($a, true) . '</pre>';
```

Will output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
    2 => 'c',
  ),
)
```

Comment: This works only when 2nd parameter is `true`. I've updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!

Comment: This worked fine, all other suggestion didn't worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

For me the right answer was

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export($var, true) . '</pre>';
```

Since `var_dump($var)` and `var_export($var)` do not return a string, you have to use `var_export($var, true)` to force `var_export` to return the result as a value.

Comment: this was already given as answer a few months ago, so no need to add it. doesnt make the page more useful. upvote the existing answer instead.

Answer (score 7):

Use output buffers: http://php.net/manual/de/function.ob-start.php

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    var_dump($_SERVER) ;
    $dump = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo "<pre> $dump </pre>";
?>
```

Yet another option would be to **use Output buffering and convert all the newlines in the dump** to `<br>` elements, e.g.

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_SERVER) ;
echo nl2br(ob_get_clean());
```

Comment: Tip: instead of `$dump = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();`, you can simply do this: `$dump = ob_get_clean();`

Comment: Instead of wrapping it in pre elements, you could also just `echo nl2br($dump)`

Answer (score 7):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to view the source code. Most Browsers will prettify the output there.

`var_dump` is the ugliest way to debug.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I like the replacement function provided by [Symfony's var dumper component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html)

Install with `composer require symfony/var-dumper` and just use `dump($var)`

It takes care of the rest. I believe there's also a bit of JS injected there to allow you to interact with the output a bit.

Answer (score 1):

For devs needing something that works in the *view source* and the *CLI*, especially useful when debugging unit tests.

```php
echo vd([['foo'=>1, 'bar'=>2]]);

function vd($in) {
  ob_start(); 
  var_dump($in);
  return "\n" . preg_replace("/=>[\r\n\s]+/", "=> ", ob_get_clean());
}
```

Yields:

```
array(1) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    'foo' => int(1)
    'bar' => int(2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar solution. I've created a snippet to replace 'vardump' with this:

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $reg) {
    echo "<pre>{$key} => '{$reg}'</pre>";
}
var_dump($variable);die;
```

Ps: I'm repeating the data with the last var_dump to get the filename and line

So this:
[image]
Became this:
[image]

Let me know if this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in `<pre>` tags to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I really love var_export(). If you like copy/paste-able code, try:

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export($data, true) . '</pre>';
```

Or even something like this for color syntax highlighting:

```
highlight_string("<?php\n\$data =\n" . var_export($data, true) . ";\n?>");
```

Comment: That `highlight_string` trick is one of the easiest ways of making `var_export` readable that I know. Deserves more upvotes!

Comment: A full copy paste of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19816742/327862 Very Lame!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't wanna stop using `var_dump($variable);die();` and using `pre` tags and loops seems overkill to me, so since I am looking at the dump in a browser, I just right click the page and choose Inspect (I use Chrome). The Elements section of the Developer Tools show the variable in a very readable format.