# PHP print_r function does not nest the printed array

Tags: php, arrays

I used the `print_r` function to print array fetched from a table in database. Instead of a nicely formatted array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [firstname] => Firstname one
            [lastname] => Lastname one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [firstname] => Firstname two
            [lastname] => Lastname two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [firstname] => Firstname three
            [lastname] => Lastname three
        )
)
```

I got inline results, like this:

```
Array ([0] => Array ([id] => 1 [firstname] => Firstname one [lastname] => Lastname one ) [1] => Array ([id] => 2 [firstname] => Firstname two...
```

This is a simple example, my actual array is nested three times, so the result is a massive block of inline string that makes readability hard.

Why do I get results such as this?

Comment: Echo <pre> before and </pre> after the print_r

Comment: To expand on that comment a bit -- `print_r()` doesn't generate HTML, it generates plain text. If you want it to display nicely in a browser, you have to add markup.

Comment: Why? Because you're printing on a web page, and the browser is re-formatting just like it does any other text.

Comment: `var_dump` , `print_r` and maybe better `var_export` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816438/make-var-dump-look-pretty/19816742#19816742 can use with `highlight_string`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens simply because you are printing plaintext straight to your webpage, which automatically reformats text, luckily there is a solution.

The following code will "pretty print" your PHP arrays.

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($array, true)."</pre>";
```

> The HTML `<pre>` tag is used for indicating preformatted text. The code
>   tag surrounds the code being marked up.
>
> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_pre_tag.htm

The 2nd parameter of `print_r()` tells the function to capture the output of `print_r()` instead of printing it as plaintext. [Learn more on the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

These two methods put together make the output to be "prettified".

---

As noted by [dognose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057547/dognose) in the comments, if you don't want to use `<pre>` tags for whatever reason, you can simply view the source code of the page you are working on and it will show the array in a "nice" fashion.

Example posted by dognose:
[image]

---

### Function

I've written a little pretty print function that will allow you to do this a bit easier...

```
function print_p($arr) {
    return "<pre>".print_r($arr, true)."</pre>";
}
```

This can save you a lot of time/effort of typing the pre tags every time. Usage:

```
echo print_p($array);
```

Comment: Or - if you want to avoid the `<pre>`-tags, just check the source code of the page. It will show the array in a "nice" fashion, without `<pre>`.

Comment: @dognose Hope you don't mind, I added that to my answer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Will accept the answer in a minute :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton The "whatever reason" is: it's more time consuming to type the String-Concatenation, than do `print_r($arr)` followed by a "right click" -> "Inspect Element" in Chrome :P

Comment: I'm sure there are other reasons too @dognose :) and in that case, why not just make a new function that includes the pretags?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica its not possible to return an echo direct from the function and everytime just to call the function ?

Comment: @CananauCristian I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. I think you are asking if you can just use `echo` inside the function, if so, the answer is yes. I generally always use `return` though.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica noo i mean realy "return echo $array;" soo that you can use that only with print_p($array)

Comment: @CananauCristian You can't return an echo, but you could just do `echo "<pre>".print_r($arr, true)."</pre>";` inside the function so you don't have to use `echo` when you call the function.