# Getting the syntax colored in browser

Tags: php, google-chrome

So I've been learning PHP and MySQL (and HTML and JavaScript and CSS but that is not relevant maybe)
and in the course the "educator" has shown things like
    var_dump()
and
    $_SERVER
in the browser and it shows a colored syntax when loaded. how did he do this?
is this a browser extension or something to do with Sublime Text 3?

Comment: You could ask them? :) It can be many things from PHP libraries to JavaScript highlight in browser.

Comment: Hard to tell what colorization you're referring to without a sample. If it's just `var_dump` output, then it's presumably the free gift that comes with xdebug: https://xdebug.org/docs/display

Answer (score 1):

As long As I know sublime doesn't provide any service like that.

It might be Chrome Extension Like this
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/phpview/nlkobfbkblfhlcobdomlhmpbbhmcbkfd

Or here is an existing stack with your answer

[Make var_dump look pretty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816438/make-var-dump-look-pretty)

Comment: The Extension you posted was the right thing! thanks!!