# why the OpenServer displays the code in a string

Tags: php

why the OpenServer displays the code in a string but not in the column as indicated in the light image. I do everything the same, but I have everything on the line?
please help me, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

this is my code:

[image]

and this is my output and all one line:

[image]

but it should be like this[original of the required output]

[image]

Comment: Column? What column are you talking about?

Comment: please dont use images for your code, chose instead to put your code in the body of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making PHP var\_dump() values display one line per value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116063/making-php-var-dump-values-display-one-line-per-value)

Answer (score 1):

You have `var_dump($x)` in there two times, which will display the array as a string like in your image. But the `echo $x[0]` is displayed/echoed  correctly in between those two - as "18".

If you want to echo all values of the array, you need a foreach loop, like

```
foreach($array as $value) { 
  echo "<p>".$value."</p>"; 
}
```

EDIT AFTER COMMENT:

Put the arrays into `pre` tags and use  `print_r($x);` instead of `var_dump($x)`, like

`<pre>print_r($x);</pre>`

Comment: I just need everything to be displayed in a column. as in this :https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUXnN.png

Comment: Try `print_r($x);` instead of `var_dump($x)`, and put it into a `<pre>` tag

Comment: but the author does not use print_r ($ x); and <pre> ( I wrote as he did