# How to get all elements with var_dump?

Tags: php

How do I get all of elements with `var_dump`? 
I have a huge array but `var_dump` prints only the first x elemets, and I need all of them to check if my sql is correct.

Comment: have you though of `echo '<pre>';print_r($array);echo '</pre>';` ?
Or `foreach($array as $v){var_dump($v);}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9998490/

Comment: The other question is very focused on xdebug, where as this just wants an alternative to the default var_dump.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($your_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will not show you type/size of the array elements as var_dump but will show you full array.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
<pre>
<?php
    print_r($var); 
?>
</pre>
```

It's a good way to see your array. The `pre` element formats it nice and readable.

Answer (score 2):

Try `print_r` e.g.

```
print_r($myarray);
```