# How to make atom php-debug show all elements of an array?

Tags: php, atom-editor

Only 31 of the 67 array elements are shown in the `watchpoints`

[image: php-debug elements]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using xdebug with atom, please check the following xdebug settings:

```
xdebug.var_display_max_depth
xdebug.var_display_max_children
xdebug.var_display_max_data
```

See also this post: [How to get xdebug var_dump to show full object/array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998490/how-to-get-xdebug-var-dump-to-show-full-object-array)

There might also be a limit on the amount of children displayed in atom.

Answer (score -1):

get_class_methods('classname'), Can only get public function

```
$class = new ReflectionClass($_brand);
$methods = $class->getMethods();
var_dump($methods);
```

Answer (score -1):

`get_class_methods()` is sensitive to the current scope, meaning if you do this:

```
class brand{
  public    function publicMethod(){}
  private   function privateMethod(){}
  protected function protectedMethod(){}

  static    function getMethods(){
    return get_class_methods(__CLASS__);
  }
}

print_r(brand::getMethods());
```

You will receive a full list of public, private, protected and static methods.