# Replace single quote with double quote php

Tags: php

This is my html code:

```
 <div style="box-sizing: border-box; 
                  color: rgb(37, 37, 37); 
            font-family: Axiforma-Regular; 
              font-size: 16px;">
 </div>
```

I want to replace these inline css double quote with single quote.

I tried this:

```
$display_box_content = '<div style="box-sizing: border-box; 
                                         color: rgb(37, 37, 37); 
                                   font-family: Axiforma-Regular; 
                                     font-size: 16px;">
                        </div>'

$display_box_content = str_replace('"', "'", $display_box_content);
```

but these does not work.

Please help!

Comment: You forgot a semicolon at the end of your first line. Other than that, your code works just fine. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef97b4719ff51e34ebeed0bf26daaa89971378d7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was using htmlentites function like this:

```
$display_box_content = htmlentities($display_box_content);
$display_box_content = str_replace('"', "'", $display_box_content);
```

so i just swapped those lines to this:

```
$display_box_content = str_replace('"', "'", $display_box_content);
$display_box_content = htmlentities($display_box_content);
```

and it worked. Thanks everybody for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `;` on line 1.

```
$display_box_content = '<div style="box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(37, 37, 37); font-family: Axiforma-Regular; font-size: 16px;"></div>'; //added a ; here
$display_box_content = str_replace('"', "'", $display_box_content);
```

This code actually works; Please see [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/8pVRC)

Answer (score 0):

You can do  like  following if you want to replace single quote with double quote in a php string.

```
  $replacedString = str_replace(chr(39), chr(34),$display_box_content);
  //chr(39) implies single quote 
  //chr(34) implies double quote
```

You can read about chr() function in php from [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_chr.asp)

Answer (score -1):

```
$display_box_content = str_replace('\'', "\"",, $display_box_content);
```

Comment: thank you bro, i edited my answer, result is : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa15d0c477b1582acfdcf338662fd033d24353cf

Comment: hey,i can see the code works in this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa15d0c477b1582acfdcf338662fd033d24353cf but if i copy paste this same code in to my local server and execute, then nothing is displayed, then this kind of some dummy string: ....string(115) "
" string(115) "
" ...is displayed

Comment: @user3856149 try setup xdebug or configure var_dump function in your php and configure. You can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998490/how-to-get-xdebug-var-dump-to-show-full-object-array

Answer (score -1):

You just have to use single-qoutes instead?

```
$display_box_content = "<div style='box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(37, 37, 37); font-family: Axiforma-Regular; font-size: 16px;'></div>"
```

Comment: as @Gyandeep Sharma already mentioned i just saw! he was faster;)

Comment: The question is about changing it using str_replace