# Xdebug - increase var_display_max_depth in Step Debugging

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

As per Xdebug Documentation:

> integer xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 3 #
> Controls how many nested levels of array elements and object properties are when variables are displayed with either xdebug_var_dump(), xdebug.show_local_vars or when making a Function Trace.
> The maximum value you can select is 1023. You can also use -1 as value to select this maximum number.
> **This setting does not have any influence on the number of children that is send to the client through the Step Debugging feature.**

However, I'm trying to display a nested object in PhpStorm, and I expectedly get this result:

[image]

Repro:

```
$n = new Map();
$n["test"] = new Map();
$n["test"]->put("lorem", new Map());
$n["test"]["lorem"]->put("ipsum", "dolor");
$m = ["m" => ["k" => ["r" => ["h" => ["test_var"]]]]];
```

So I have two questions:

- Why can Xdebug display the values in the nested array but can't when using other objects?
- How can I "force" Xdebug to drill deeper into the `Ds\Map` object?

Comment: I am aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998490/how-to-get-xdebug-var-dump-to-show-full-object-array but it is not practical in my use case to dump into a file each time, as the data structure is relatively large and has many complex objects in it

Comment: What is `Ds\Map` ? PECL one https://www.php.net/manual/en/ds.installation.php  or PHP version of it https://packagist.org/packages/php-ds/php-ds ?

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://postimg.cc/948dSDZv using Windows 10 x64, PHP 7.4.16 NTS x64, Xdebug 3.0.3, PhpStorm 2020.3.3 x64. Using PECL version of Ds 1.3.0: https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ds/1.3.0/php_ds-1.3.0-7.4-nts-vc15-x64.zip

Comment: Just tried the PHP polyfill version instead (https://github.com/php-ds/polyfill) .. and got that "can not get property" error message.

Comment: @LazyOne and I just tried the PECL version and it worked as expected.  I really appreciate confirming the bug. I'll be filing a report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xdebug and PhpStorm should both be able to handle both cases. The `var_display_max_children` setting is indeed not for step debugging, but the protocol allows for PhpStorm to request for more information.

It's either possible that there is a bug here, or that you have an older version of PhpStorm that has some issues talking to Xdebug about this.

In either case, I recommend that you file a bug report at https://bugs.xdebug.org with a *short* and *self-contained* script. Please follow the instructions at https://xdebug.org/reporting-bugs

Comment: I really appreciate you taking time to answer my question. I am running recent versions of PHP, Xdebug and PHPStorm. PHP version (CLI, running as remote interpreter on WSL 1, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, up-to-date): postimg.cc/7bc5CDwc  PHPStorm version: postimg.cc/sBVxFg4B 
I was running on polyfill and I'll be trying PECL extension shortly and installing on Windows and report back.

Comment: If you want the bug fixed, then file a bug report. This is not the place for that.

Comment: I just tested the PECL version on PHP7.4 and PHP 8.0, and it works as expected. I'll be filing a bug report.